# When is NCE a better choice than softmax (to train RNN LM)

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I am currently working on RNN LM using TensorFlow. I started from the TensorFlow tutorial ([tuto](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#recurrent-neural-networks); [sources](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py)), and customized the script (https://github.com/pltrdy/tf_rnnlm/).

I seems to be widely agreed that Noise Contrastive Estimation (NCE) runs faster. So I ran a benchmark running on 4 configuration using 4 loss function (I especially wanted to test softmax vs NCE). Results are shown [here](https://github.com/pltrdy/tf_rnnlm/blob/master/benchmark.md).

Speed (word per second) differences are not significant enough to draw any conclusion.

I am not sure what to think about it: Is NCE stronger on very large? Did I missed something?

Please tell me if you have any clues,
Thx

```
pltrdy
```

---

Edit:
Also [tensorflow refers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py#L43) to [this paper (sec. 3)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.2007v2.pdf) which states "With  the  proposed  approach **[sampled softmax?]**,  the  computational complexity of training becomes **constant** with respect to the size of the target vocabulary"

Which is not (at all) the case on our benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

NCE or sampled softmax is essential for training LMs with large vocabularies. If you increase your vocabulary size to say 500k, you will see a significant difference between NCE and full softmax. The link to your benchmarks appears to be broken. But, if you use a large vocabulary, you should see the difference.